# Regex to find empty foreach loop

Tags: php, regex

I am using a regex pattern to find all empty foreach loops in my code, so something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($object->method() AS $something){
}
```

So far i have this regex, but it is not working:

```
foreach\([^\)(?=\s*\{)]*\)\s*\{\s*\}
```

To explain the pattern a bit more, i added some comments here with ?#:

```
foreach\( ?# Search for 'foreach(' string
[^ ?#Start group to capture everything which is not..
\) ?#equal to ')'
(?=\s*\{) ?# with \s*\{ after it. so '){' with possibility of spaces inbetween
]* ?# End is not equal to group, and capture 0 to inf characters of it
\)\s*\{ ?# The foreach statement is closed with ){, with possibility of spaces inbetween
\s* ?# Whitespaces
\} ?# Closing tag
```

However, it seems to go wrong at '(' in '->method()'

I think the expression between the square brackets is not valid, but i cannot figure out why.

Comment: You can't put a lookahead inside `[ ]`, it just contains a list of characters and character classes.

Comment: hmm too bad. Any idea for a different approach to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
foreach\((?:(?!\)\s*{).)*\)\s*{\s*}
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oP2mJ6/2)

> cannot figure out why

Characters in `[ ]` are taken literally so lookaround inside `[ ]` is not doing what you intended to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
foreach\(.*\)\S*\{[\s\n\r]*\}
```

By using `\S` to identify whitespace, you can support nested `()` inside your `foreach ( )` block.

https://regex101.com/r/pC7uU8/2

Comment: `\S` is everything except whitespace, I think you mean `\s`.